# Reference request: lower sets of a preorder form a lattice

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, order-theory, lattice-theory

Consider a set $S$ with a preorder $\preceq$ (a *preorder* is a reflexive and transitive relation).  A lower set $A$ of $S$ is defined as a subset of $S$ such that for all  $x \in S$ and $y \in A$, if $x \preceq y$ then $x \in A$.

I believe the set of all lower sets of $S$ form a complete, distributive lattice. Is there a reference which states this?

Comment: It is a clearly a complete sublattice of the power set lattice, hence complete and distributive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even better than completely distributive: it's a complete ring of sets, or abstractly, a "Stone lattice". Moreover, this construction describes a dual categorical equivalence between posets and Stone lattices. See [Section 6.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=IBZeDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA201) of my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (second edition).

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a reference which states this?**

Yes. You will find this assertion in
[Exercise 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=ePqVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121) of Chapter 5 (Complete Lattices),
Section 5 (Infinite Distributivity), of the book:

Lattice Theory, Volume 25, Part 2
Garrett Birkhoff
American Mathematical Soc., Dec 31, 1940.

[More specifically, in Exercise 6,
Birkhoff asks the reader to show that
if $\mathbf{P}$ is a poset, then 
the lattice of monotone maps $\mathbf{P}\to \mathbf{2}$ is
a completely distributive, complete lattice.
You can derive the statement you want by identifying
a monotone map with its zero set. Birkhoff gives a hint for this exercise, which is essentially the same remark Goldstern makes in his May 14 comment on this question.]